# Invariant failure opCtx->lockState() ->isDbLockedForMode(db, MODE_IS) ... Got signal: 6 (Aborted)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, wiredtiger

I have a replica set(PSS) in mongod version 4.2.0 Community Edition installed on Ubuntu 18.04LTS have enough disk space in each node, but also a data bearing replica set has gone down suddenly. And the log messages I attached here. Can any one let me know waht is the root cause, so that I can rectify, or else does it a product issue?

```
2021-03-17T06:46:50.620+0000 F  -        [conn1139390] Invariant failure opCtx->lockState()->isDbLockedForMode(db, MODE_IS) || (db.compare("local") == 0 && opCtx->lockState()->isLocked()) src/mongo/db/catalog/database_holder_impl.cpp 74
2021-03-17T06:46:50.620+0000 F  -        [conn1139390]
***aborting after invariant() failure
2021-03-17T06:46:50.651+0000 F  -        [conn1139390] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

------------------------[conn1139390] log--------------------------------

```
    2021-03-17T06:46:28.452+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn1139390] received client metadata from XX.XX.21.XXX:52690 conn1139390: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceTL", version: "4.2.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "18.04" } }
    2021-03-17T06:46:28.639+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn1139390] Successfully authenticated as principal __system on local from client xx.xx.21.xxx:52690

2021-03-17T06:46:50.620+0000 F  -        [conn1139390] Invariant failure opCtx->lockState()->isDbLockedForMode(db, MODE_IS) || (db.compare("local") == 0 && opCtx->lockState()->isLocked()) src/mongo/db/catalog/database_holder_impl.cpp 74
2021-03-17T06:46:50.620+0000 F  -        [conn1139390]
2021-03-17T06:46:50.651+0000 F  -        [conn1139390] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug encounter this version, please check this Jira Ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-55247